# How to remove bevel artifacts on an unusual edge?

Tags: bevel, artifacts

Hey guys I am in a bit of a stump. I am using blender 2.92 and I have an issue trying to bevel an edge near a curve. So see here before beveling [image: image before bevel] and image after beveling [image: after bevel] I could only bevel using the Ctrl + B command. When I use a modifier it does nothing to the edge no matter what options I change. In the second image you can see that there is a bevel but also there are planes sticking out. So if anyone has an idea how to remove those planes. They are probably from overlapping geometry but I don't know how to remove them. The scale of the model is set to 1 also. Thanks.

Comment: your topology is bad, it won't allow a good bevel, you need to retopologize

Comment: @moonboots if I was to use remesh modifier would that fix the problem?

Comment: maybe, you could also try a trick: extrude a bit the large face, then bevel. But maybe share your file so that we can give a try: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks for advice. I embedded the images. How would you solve this problem?

Comment: @moonboots thanks I will give it a go. I also thought to dissolve the faces on the curved side along the curve and make one large face where the gap is and then bevel the edge. Also, thanks for telling me about the trick, so when I extrude the large face which edge do I bevel the extruded one or the original one?

Comment: please share your file, it's very hard to guess without the real object  ;)  https://pasteall.org/blend

Comment: @moonboots I have uploaded the file. https://pasteall.org/blend/3c9a782d0f2e41129a380e5aa3c3f823

Answer (score 0):

Your topology is a bit messy but you can do that:

- First apply the scale of your object, otherwise it won't bevel correctly
- Select the big face, extrude:

[image]

- Bevel, choose the amount of segments in the *Operator* box (bottom left of your 3D view once you've beveled):

[image]

- *Shade Smooth* if needed.

Comment: Thanks @moonboots